# How do you replace double quotes with a blank space in Java?

Tags: java, replace, quotes, regex

For example:

```
"I don't like these "double" quotes"
```

and I want the output to be

```
I don't like these double quotes
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`String#replace()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

To replace them with spaces (as per your question title):

```
System.out.println("I don't like these \"double\" quotes".replace("\"", " "));
```

The above can also be done with characters:

```
System.out.println("I don't like these \"double\" quotes".replace('"', ' '));
```

To remove them (as per your example):

```
System.out.println("I don't like these \"double\" quotes".replace("\"", ""));
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need regex for this. Just a character-by-character replace is sufficient. You can use [`String#replace()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) for this.

```
String replaced = original.replace("\"", " ");
```

Note that you can also use an empty string `""` instead to replace with. Else the spaces would double up.

```
String replaced = original.replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: I agree, RegEx is way overkill.

Comment: As turns out in the newer question the OP has asked here, this is actually to become part of a bigger (and troublesome) regex piece. But yes, regex is indeed way overkill for this particular find&replace piece.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
string tmp = "Hello 'World'";
tmp.replace("'", "");
```

But that will just replace single quotes.  To replace double quotes, you must first escape them, like so:

```
string tmp = "Hello, \"World\"";
tmp.replace("\"", "");
```

You can replace it with a space, or just leave it empty (I believe you wanted it to be left blank, but your question title implies otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, so you need to say

```
sInputString = sInputString("\"","");
```

not just the right side of the `=`