# Text Parsing with Quotation Marks MapReduce Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, mapreduce

I have a document that contains numerous strings that I need to parse. 
Each line is of the form:

```
PageID  Title   Date    <XML Article>
```

The format of the string is as follows:

```
12146635    Pardulus of Laon    2009-11-01 10:51:01 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<articles loadtime="0 sec" rendertime="0.002 sec" totaltime="0.002 sec"><article><paragraph><sentence id="12146635/0"><bold><link synthetic="true"><target>Pardulus of Laon</target></link></bold><extension extension_name="ref">Pardoul, Pardule de Laon, Pardulus Laudunensis.</extension><space/>was<space/><link><target>bishop of Laon</target></link>, France, from 847 to 857.</sentence> <sentence id="12146635/1">He is known for his participation in theological controversy.</sentence> <sentence id="12146635/2">A letter of his to<space/><link><target>Hincmar of Reims</target></link><space/>is known<extension extension_name="ref"><link type="external" href="http://www.forumromanum.org/literature/pardulus_laudunensis/hincmar.html"/>, page in French, online text in Latin.</extension>.</sentence></paragraph><heading level="2">Notes</heading><paragraph><extension extension_name="references"/></paragraph><paragraph><sentence id="12146635/3"><link><target>Category:9th-century bishops</target></link><link><target>Category:Bishops of Laon</target></link></sentence></paragraph><paragraph><sentence id="12146635/4"><link><target>nl:Pardulus van Laon</target></link></sentence></paragraph></article></articles>   Pardulus of Laon was bishop of Laon, France, from 847 to 857. He is known for his participation in theological controversy. A letter of his to Hincmar of Reims is known.\n\n
```

I am writing a MapReduce program to remove all the XML tags from the fourth column and get the following output schema:

```
Title, Text
```

Where `Text` is the `<XML Article>` without XML tags and some more case sensoring. For the above case, the output will be as follows:

```
pardulus of laon, pardule de laon pardulus laudunensis bishop of laon france from to he is known for his participation in theological controversy a letter of his to hincmar of reims is known page in french online text in latin notes category th century bishops category bishops of laon nl pardulus van laon pardulus of laon was bishop of laon france from to he is known for his participation in theological controversy a letter of his to hincmar of reims is known
```

Now, the problem I am facing is with the double quotation marks `" "` within the article tags themselves. So far, I have managed to write the following code:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] line = value.toString().split("\t"); 
        String title = line[1].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").trim()
                .replaceAll(" +", " ").toLowerCase();
        String text = value.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").trim()
                .replaceAll(" +", " ").toLowerCase();
        context.write(new Text(title), new Text(text));
        }
    }
```

I do not know the string coming before hand and so I cannot use `replaceAll(""", "\"")`, which is escaping the double quotes.

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Instead of using a regex to manipulate the XML content, it would be a good idea to use an XML parser, because, currently it is double quotes, tomorrow it might be single quotes, escaped characters in XML, special characters, etc.

Comment: @MJSG comment makes sense. Pls follow that. For the part of replace double quotes, you need to escape it. "\"". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360231/how-do-you-replace-double-quotes-with-a-blank-space-in-java