# org.json.JSONException: Missing value at character 2

Tags: java, json, tomcat

I am trying to parse the below json response using following code but the code is working fine on normal eclipse program but failing on `tomcat (java 1.8)`

> 2016-12-20 00:18:17,146 DEBUG c.a.f.u.s.UpdateFileUploadData [Thread-35]
>   sTempOutput::"[{\"Status\":\"Success\",\"MonthlyReportId\":\"R/I -
>   000913\"},{\"Status\":\"Success\",\"MonthlyReportId\":\"R/I -
>   001473\"},{\"Status\":\"Success\",\"MonthlyReportId\":\"R/I -
>   001474\"}]"
>       2016-12-20 00:18:17,146 DEBUG c.a.f.u.s.UpdateFileUploadData [Thread-35]
>   transformed:[{\"Status\":\"Success\",\"MonthlyReportId\":\"R/I -
>   000913\"},{\"Status\":\"Success\",\"MonthlyReportId\":\"R/I -
>   001473\"},{\"Status\":\"Success\",\"MonthlyReportId\":\"R/I -
>   001474\"}]

```
            jsonObject = jsonObject.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
            if(jsonObject.startsWith("\"")){
                jsonObject = jsonObject.substring(1, jsonObject.length()-1);
            } // replacing the " from start and end.
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("transformed:{}", jsonObject);
            }
            org.json.JSONArray array = new org.json.JSONArray(jsonObject);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("array:::{}", array);
            }
            DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter();
            for (int start = 0 ;start<array.length(); start++){
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(start);
                String status = (String)object.get("Status");
                String monthlyReportId = (String)object.get("MonthlyReportId");
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("status:::{}", status);
                    logger.debug("monthlyReportId:::{}", monthlyReportId);
                }
            }
```

This is killing me.  I have also tried it -

```
jsonObject = jsonObject.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "");
jsonObject = jsonObject.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
```

rest remains the same.

Comment: You should not need to replace the backslashes - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858914/jackson-parser-cant-read-backslash-quotation-marks-in-string

Comment: Still the same issue. org.json.JSONException: Missing value at character 2.

Comment: Still the same issue. org.json.JSONException: Missing value at character    
   if(jsonObject.startsWith("\"")){
    jsonObject = jsonObject.substring(1, jsonObject.length()-1);
   }
   
   org.json.JSONArray array = new org.json.JSONArray(jsonObject);
   if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("array:::{}", array);
   }
   DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter();
   for (int start = 0 ;start<array.length(); start++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(start);

Comment: Is the original text NOT well formed JSON?  Test it at http://jsonlint.com/  If it is well formed then you should not have to manipulate the text

Comment: after formating the json i am getting some below in logs -

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Missing value at character 3 when i formated the json as per the standard

Comment: the json is working fibe on the validator.

Comment: please show the JSON that is working on *the validator*